# How tall does the ceiling have to be for trees to grow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building an underground orchard in Minecraft. What is the minimum height the ceiling needs to be in order for trees to grow?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19539/in-minecraft-whats-the-best-way-to-harvest-wheat-and-wood-underground)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Back when there was only one kind of sapling, it was easy: you needed 6 blocks of headroom. However now there are many types of tree, each with different requirements. Each sapling type requires this amount of space above the sapling:

- **Oak**  needs 5+ spaces
- **Birch** needs 6+ spaces
- **Spruce** needs 7+ spaces (single sapling)
- **Jungle**  needs 7+ spaces (single sapling)
- **Acacia**  needs 7+ spaces

As for the trees which require saplings be placed in a 2x2 square:

- **Giant Jungle** needs 13+ spaces
- **Giant Spruce** needs 16+ spaces
- **Dark Oak** needs 7+ spaces

Source: [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sapling)

Comment: I put 4 jungle trees into a 10x16x20 room and it still isn't growing after many hours and bonemeal.